# pandas style tag give "ValueError: style is not supported for non-unique indices"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to give the negative numbers in mine data frame a red color.
But when trying to achieve with the following code

```
def color_negative_red(val):
    """
    Takes a scalar and returns a string with
    the css property `'color: red'` for negative
    strings, black otherwise.
    """
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color

s = df05.style.applymap(color_negative_red)

print(s)
```

I got the following Value Error "ValueError: style is not supported for non-unique indices."

Where must i look to get the right output?

Comment: Posting this in case someone needs this: I Faced this problem recently. After many attempts, I realized the names of the columns in my dataframe were the problem, as they were not unique. A simple command to rename the columns solved the issue, next are some examples: df.columns = range(df.size) df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'] df.T.reset_index(drop=True).T

Comment: @dmenesesg thnx, indeed that was my problem too.

Comment: @dmenesesg `df.size` is the number of rows times number of columns, but we only want the number of columns. The generic code is: `df.columns = range(len(df.columns))`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe you need unique default index values by [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `drop=True`:

```
s = df05.reset_index(drop=True).style.applymap(color_negative_red)
```

Comment: What about if you want to set a new `CategoricalIndex` e.g. `cm.set_index(pandas.CategoricalIndex(['TN', 'FN', 'FP', 'FN'])).style`? This produces the same exception.

Comment: @DanielleMadeley - Unfortunataly not supported yet.

Comment: @jezrael do you know why this requirement for styling exists? Requirement sounds irrelevant to me. Thank you

Comment: My data frame has unique indices but still does not work. Even trying the above, resetting index, does not work.

Comment: @JQTs Try `df.columns = range(len(df.columns))`

Answer (score 2):

This can be one of two possible problems, either your index has duplicate names (check with `df.index`) or your columns have duplicate names (check with `df.columns`).

If your index has duplicates, do:

```py
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

If your columns have duplicates, do:

```py
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
```

Comment: imo, this is a more complete answer as it highlights two potential reasons (2nd for columns)